# What might be the English name for this chilli?

Tags: chili-peppers

[image]

I got this picture from searching google hence some unrelated content.

Kasa/khasa Morris is the name of this chilli in the first pic and it is often used in Bangladeshi cuisine.  They usually use the green one I.e it’s a green chilli.  I’m trying to find the English name for it so I can get an idea of the Scoville heat rating for it.

I am currently using this.  Does anyone know what the English name is and what sort of heat profile it might have.

Comment: You know what happens to green chili if you leave them alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a definitive answer, but I suspect that the name you have for it is the english name. There are many many varieties of chili and many of them are not found in the english speaking parts of the world, so the local name is the english name.

I googled the name as you provided it and found that it probably is called an unhelpful "green chili". It is very probable that the "morris" part is a corruption of "morich" which translates to pepper (see the entries for morich on [this list of Bangladeshi spices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bangladeshi_spices)). Within that list is an entry for "green chili pepper" which has the local name of "kancha morich" or "kancha lonka", which seems to be a variant name with associated recipes.

I have been unable to find a Scoville rating for this chili or even which of the species of *Capsicum* it is, but the rating is normally done on dried chili (I think!). There is an excellent summary of chili varieties and types [in this page](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/engl/Caps_fru.html), which might give you some direction.