# Why is this cayenne pepper very hot?

Tags: pepper

As far as I'm aware cayenne pepper is meant to be medium hot(which is what I wanted) and not very hot.

In order to ensure I am getting the genuine cayenne pepper I was trying a speciaist store (https://www.hollandandbarrett.com/shop/product/the-vital-ingredient-cayenne-pepper-60096681?skuid=096681) since general stores may have mixes or false labels.

However the packet says it is very hot which cayenne shouldn't be?  Or are there varieties within cayenne pepper which are hot and this could be one of them?

Comment: One person's "very hot" is another's "medium hot".  It simply isn't clearly defined.

Comment: Recommend reading up on the Scoville Scale: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale

Comment: As already explained ***7*** almost identical questions ago - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/102488/42066 'cayenne' is not a single pepper cultivar, it's a family. Some are hotter than others. All are generally 'hot'. btw, H&B are charging you 3x the regular price for this. Avoid. (Their market is 'health'.. make of that what you will)

Comment: @Tetsujin well I knew there are many varieties of cayenne pepper but I was under the impression that all these varieties were mildly spicey .

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't even come in a convenient package! Non resealable, and no shaker even.

Comment: James - if you're in the UK, take yourself to the nearest Asda; grab a bag of their fresh mixed chillies to test. It will contain variants of [these could be green, yellow or red]… a couple of fresnos/jalapeños [medium-size, triangular, 'medium hot'] a few piri piri or bird's eye [small, hot] & a scotch bonnet [quite large, lumpy, wrinkled, very aromatic & very hot]. They don't tell you really what's in the bag, but that's the general types they use. Try them all, raw. 'Cayenne' is somewhere between the fresno & bird's eye for 'heat'.